# Android: How to setTag with Adapter

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, getter-setter

I have following situation: I have `PostBaseAdapter` where I initialize my views and `MainActivity` where I want to set Checkbox with switch parameter by `getTag()` but I don't know how to `setTag()` for my checkbox and where.

```
public class PostBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<PostValue> postValueArrayList;

    public PostBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PostValue> postValueArrayList) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.postValueArrayList = postValueArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return postValueArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PostValue getItem(int position) {
        return postValueArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        PostValue postValue = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(postValue.getBrand());
        viewHolder.tvPublishDate.setText(postValue.getDate());
        viewHolder.cost.setText(postValue.getPrice());
        viewHolder.descriptionOfItem.setText(postValue.getDescription());
        viewHolder.deliveryTime.setText("Cрок доставки: "+postValue.getDeliveryTime()+" дней");
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(false);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        Button order;
         CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView tvTitle, tvPublishDate, cost, deliveryTime, descriptionOfItem;

        public ViewHolder(View item) {

            tvTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvPublishDate = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvPublishDate);
            cost = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.cost);
            deliveryTime = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.delivery_time);
            descriptionOfItem = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.description);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            order = (Button) item.findViewById(R.id.order);
        }
    }
}
```

and MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    order = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    lvPcsPost = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPcsPost);
    lvPcsPost.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    lvPcsPost.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (postValueArrayList != null && postValueArrayList.size() > 0) {
            }
        }
    });

    new PostAsync().execute();
    //Установка Статус Бара определенного цвета
    Window window = this.getWindow();

    window.setStatusBarColor(this.

    getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    Paper.init(this);
}

class PostAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    XMLHelper helper;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Загрузка", "Ждите, идет загрузка автозапчастей ...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        helper = new XMLHelper();
        helper.get(getIntent().getStringExtra("level")); // Передаем Интент с артикулом из поиска
        postValueArrayList = helper.getPostsList();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        PostBaseAdapter postBaseAdapter = new PostBaseAdapter(MainActivity.this, postValueArrayList);
        lvPcsPost.setAdapter(postBaseAdapter);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}

public void checkBoxClick(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getTag().toString()) {
        case "0":
            if (checked) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ЩЕЛК:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you quite well. Can't you use `viewHolder.checkBox.setTag()` and the same for `getTag()`..?

Comment: So if i correct understand i need viewHolder initialize in MainActivity and from there get getTag() for switch?

Comment: I still don't understand what's bugging you, sorry. You can set the tag in `onCreateView` for each of the checkboxes. Later you can anywhere get the tag, if you have a reference to the checkbox.

Comment: Vucko do you have a skype for fast communicate? Android say me like this in LogCat: 07-10 12:29:45.725 2769-2787/com.sales.autoparts.autoparts E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f3cba18cc40
07-10 12:29:47.046 2769-2769/com.sales.autoparts.autoparts W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=636.7969, y[0]=216.13281, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER,